# Correct modification of state arrays in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add an element to the end of a `state` array, is this the correct way to do it?

```
this.state.arrayvar.push(newelement);
this.setState({ arrayvar:this.state.arrayvar });
```

I'm concerned that modifying the array in-place with `push` might cause trouble - is it safe?

The alternative of making a copy of the array, and `setState`ing that seems wasteful.

Comment: I think you can use react immutability helpers. see this: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html#simple-push

Comment: setState in state array check my solution.<br/>
<br>
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59711447/9762736

Answer (score 983, accepted):

The [React docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html) says:

> Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

Your `push` will mutate the state directly and that could potentially lead to error prone code, even if you are "resetting" the state again afterwards. For example, it could lead to that some lifecycle methods like `componentDidUpdate` won’t trigger.

The recommended approach in later React versions is to use an *updater* function when modifying states to prevent race conditions:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  arrayvar: [...prevState.arrayvar, newelement]
}))
```

The memory "waste" is not an issue compared to the errors you might face using non-standard state modifications.

**Alternative syntax for earlier React versions**

You can use `concat` to get a clean syntax since it returns a new array:

```
this.setState({ 
  arrayvar: this.state.arrayvar.concat([newelement])
})
```

In ES6 you can use the [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
this.setState({
  arrayvar: [...this.state.arrayvar, newelement]
})
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of when a race condition would occur?

Comment: Note that this answer only applies in case you want **only** to add/remove items. If you wanted to update elements in the array, you could get in trouble if it held objects. Consider this code: `var a = [1,2,3, {a:1}]; var b = a.slice(); b[3].a = 2; console.log(a[3].a);`

Comment: @VitalyB In that case, use underscore/jquery extend or some immutable library (like react immutability helper) instead of concat.

Comment: Even though the original reference gets changed, the setState call will call the render pass again, and unless you have something like PureRenderMixin turned on, you'll get your new render just fine. Is there anything else inherently wrong with `this.setState({arr: this.state.arr.push(item)})`?

Comment: @Qiming `push` returns the new array length so that won’t work. Also, `setState` is async and React can queue several state changes into a single render pass.

Comment: @ChristopherCamps I think that's another discussion. You can treat the second setState as callback from the first setState. Example in ES6 syntax: `this.SetState({ arr: this.state.arr.push(item)}, () => { this.setState({ this.state.arr.push(item2)}) })`

Comment: @mindeavor say you have an animationFrame that looks for parameters in this.state, and another method that changes some other parameters on state change. There could be some frames where the state has changed but not reflected in the method that listens for the change, because setState is async.

Comment: See @NealeU's answer below for the correct way to handle the race condition that ChristopherCamps mentions. That seems like a more robust way to handle lists in general.

Comment: @ChristopherCamps This answer does not encourage calling `setState` twice, it shows two similar examples of setting state array without mutating it directly.

Comment: @David I would advise updating your answer to include @NealeU's version also. Here's how I would do it now to avoid mutating anything AND be safe for repeat calls: `this.setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    arrayvar: state.arrayvar.concat([newelement])
}));`

Comment: An easy way to treat a state array as immutable these days is: `let list = Array.from(this.state.list); list.push('woo'); this.setState({list});` Modify to your style preferences of course.

Comment: Now with objects! `let obj = Object.assign({}, this.state.obj); obj.woo = 'wow'; this.setState({obj});`

Comment: This answer really does need updating to put the callback approach first, otherwise it's doing people a disservice.  Perhaps I'll try another edit having had my attempt to underline the risks that @ChristopherCamps pointed out, reverted by the author.

Comment: @David Where did the prevState come from and can you explain how the arrow function operates in your example above?

Comment: what about not using push but instead inserting in the middle using splice, we know splice affects the array itself. do we need to copy it using slice(0) and then splice it and assign it? does this seem reasonable resource optimization? why not modify it directly then setting any random state to update it, won't it make the same effect?

Comment: How can i prevent the duplicate after contacting two arrays when setState? i use this way `this.state.arrayvar.concat([newelement])`

Answer (score 167):

Easiest, if you are using `ES6`.

```
initialArray = [1, 2, 3];

newArray = [ ...initialArray, 4 ]; // --> [1,2,3,4]
```

New array will be `[1,2,3,4]`

to update your state in **React**

```
this.setState({
  arrayvar:[...this.state.arrayvar, newelement]
});
```

[Learn more about array destructuring](https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read#leanpub-auto-array-destructuring)

Comment: Append or prepend is quite straightforward. What about search and replace? For example array of objects. I need to update one object searching by id?

Comment: Your questions doesn't concern the OP question directly

Comment: When is `prevState` needed in `setState()`? ...or is `prevState` dated?

Comment: @ChanceSmith: it is needed in *StateLess* answer too. Do not depend in state update on the state itself. Official doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: @Sisir and anyone wondering [how to update an object within an array in the state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28121272/1218980).

Comment: @RayCoder log and check the value of arrayvar, looks like it is not array.

Comment: this.state = {
   suggestions: [{ id: "Thailand", text: "Thailand" }],
    };
    this.setState( {suggestions:  [...this.state.suggestions,[{ id: "India", text: "India" }]]  } );
I tried this and using concat one . but both are useless...

Answer (score 72):

The simplest way with `ES6`:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    array: [...prevState.array, newElement]
}))
```

Comment: Sorry, in my case i want to push an array into array. ```tableData = [['test','test']]``` After pushed my new array ```tableData = [['test','test'],['new','new']]```.
how to push this @David and @Ridd

Comment: @Johncy If you would like to get `[['test','test'],['new','new']]` try: `this.setState({
      tableData: [...this.state.tableData, ['new', 'new']]`

Comment: `this.setState({
            tableData: [...this.state.tableData ,[item.student_name,item.homework_status_name,item.comments===null?'-':item.comments] ]
            });` It inserts the new array two times
        `this.state.tableData.push([item.student_name,item.homework_status_name,item.comments===null?'-':item.comments]);` It achieves the desired thing i want. but its not the correct way i think.

Answer (score 45):

Currently so many people facing problem to update the useState hook state. I use this approach to update it safely and wanted to share it here.

This is my state

```
const [state, setState] = useState([])
```

Suppose I have a object name `obj1` and I want it to append in my state. I will suggest to do it like this

```
setState(prevState => [...prevState, obj1])
```

This will safely insert the object at the end and also keep the state consistency

Comment: THIS is the correct way to update a state when its new value depends on the previous one. Docs: *If the next state depends on the current state, we recommend using the updater function form:* `setState((state) => ...`, see https://en.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate -- State updates do NOT happen immediately, so when using the original state variable, some updates may get overwritten by new ones.

Comment: @MarcinWojnarski Except that it doesn't work when stuff ought to be appended concurrently…

Answer (score 33):

React may batch updates, and therefore the correct approach is to provide setState with a function that performs the update.

For the React update addon, the following will reliably work:

```
this.setState( state => update(state, {array: {$push: [4]}}) );
```

or for concat():

```
this.setState( state => ({
    array: state.array.concat([4])
}));
```

The following shows what https://jsbin.com/mofekakuqi/7/edit?js,output as an example of what happens if you get it wrong.

The setTimeout() invocation correctly adds three items because React will not batch updates within a setTimeout callback (see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/reactjs/G6pljvpTGX0/0ihYw2zK9dEJ).

The buggy onClick will only add "Third", but the fixed one, will add F, S and T as expected.

```
class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      array: []
    }

    setTimeout(this.addSome, 500);
  }

  addSome = () => {
      this.setState(
        update(this.state, {array: {$push: ["First"]}}));
      this.setState(
        update(this.state, {array: {$push: ["Second"]}}));
      this.setState(
        update(this.state, {array: {$push: ["Third"]}}));
    };

  addSomeFixed = () => {
      this.setState( state => 
        update(state, {array: {$push: ["F"]}}));
      this.setState( state => 
        update(state, {array: {$push: ["S"]}}));
      this.setState( state => 
        update(state, {array: {$push: ["T"]}}));
    };



  render() {

    const list = this.state.array.map((item, i) => {
      return <li key={i}>{item}</li>
    });
       console.log(this.state);

    return (
      <div className='list'>
        <button onClick={this.addSome}>add three</button>
        <button onClick={this.addSomeFixed}>add three (fixed)</button>
        <ul>
        {list}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
};


ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Is there really a case where it happens ?
If we simply do ```this.setState(
update(this.state, {array: {$push: ["First", "Second", "Third"]}})
)```

Comment: @Albizia I think you should find a colleague and discuss it with them.  There is no batching issue if you are making only one setState call.  The point is to show that React batches updates, so yes... there is really a case, which is what you can find in the JSBin version of the above code.  
Almost all of the answers in this thread fail to address this, so there will be a lot of code out there that sometimes goes wrong

Comment: `state.array = state.array.concat([4])` this mutates the previous state object.

Comment: @EmileBergeron The difference is that modified `state` (a copy of this.state) as provided to the callback.  It does not modified `this.state`

Comment: `state` *is* the previous state object.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Thank you for your persistence. I eventually looked back and saw what my brain was refusing to see, and checked the docs, so I'll edit.

Comment: Good! It's really easy to get wrong as immutability in JS is non-obvious (even more so when dealing with the API of a library).

Answer (score 31):

If you are using **functional** components in React

```
const [cars, setCars] = useState([{
  name: 'Audi',
  type: 'sedan'
}, {
  name: 'BMW',
  type: 'sedan'
}])

...

const newCar = {
  name: 'Benz',
  type: 'sedan'
}

const updatedCarsArray = [...cars, newCar];

setCars(updatedCarsArray);
```

Answer (score 21):

As @nilgun mentioned in the comment, you can use the react [immutability helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html). I've found this to be super useful.

From the docs:

**Simple push**

```
var initialArray = [1, 2, 3];
var newArray = update(initialArray, {$push: [4]}); // => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

*initialArray is still [1, 2, 3].*

Comment: The React immutability helpers are described as deprecated in the documentation.  https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper should now be used instead.

Comment: This answer and this comment is the real thing, and I appreciate taking time to write it in such a concise way - both of you. `immutability-helper` expresses this concern and has lot of thoughts and code in this direction.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using functional component please use this as below.

```
const [chatHistory, setChatHistory] = useState([]); // define the state

const chatHistoryList = [...chatHistory, {'from':'me', 'message':e.target.value}]; // new array need to update
setChatHistory(chatHistoryList); // update the state
```

Comment: mate, I was strugling for 12hrs had no clues what was going on, you saved my life

Comment: @HiệpNguyễn nice

Answer (score 1):

```
this.setState(preState=>({arrayvar:[...prevState.arrayvar,newelement]}))
```

this will work to solve this problem.

Comment: my problem exactly not the same but your square brackets same my day thanks :) 

Answer (score 0):

For added new element into the array, `push()` should be the answer.

For remove element and update state of array, below code works for me. `splice(index, 1)` can not work.

```
const [arrayState, setArrayState] = React.useState<any[]>([]);
...

// index is the index for the element you want to remove
const newArrayState = arrayState.filter((value, theIndex) => {return index !== theIndex});
setArrayState(newArrayState);
```

Comment: `push` mutates the array, [which is an anti-pattern in React.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37755997/1218980)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 2020, Reactjs Hook example that I thought could help others. I am using it to add new rows to a Reactjs table. Let me know if I could improve on something.

Adding a new element to a functional state component:

Define the state data:

```js
    const [data, setData] = useState([
        { id: 1, name: 'John', age: 16 },
        { id: 2, name: 'Jane', age: 22 },
        { id: 3, name: 'Josh', age: 21 }
    ]);
```

Have a button trigger a function to add a new element

```js
<Button
    // pass the current state data to the handleAdd function so we can append to it.
    onClick={() => handleAdd(data)}>
    Add a row
</Button>
```

```js
function handleAdd(currentData) {

        // return last data array element
        let lastDataObject = currentTableData[currentTableData.length - 1]

        // assign last elements ID to a variable.
        let lastID = Object.values(lastDataObject)[0] 

        // build a new element with a new ID based off the last element in the array
        let newDataElement = {
            id: lastID + 1,
            name: 'Jill',
            age: 55,
        }

        // build a new state object 
        const newStateData = [...currentData, newDataElement ]

        // update the state
        setData(newStateData);

        // print newly updated state
        for (const element of newStateData) {
            console.log('New Data: ' + Object.values(element).join(', '))
        }

}
```

Comment: What if instead of adding, I wanted to remove an element from the array?

Comment: @Ken what kind of array are you working with? Your array object should have a built in remove function built in. You'd trigger the removal and then update the state.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is update a value outside the state and do a forceupdate(), the less stuff managed by react the better since you have more control over what is updated.
Also creating a new array for every update may be too expensive if the updates are fast

Comment: Your answer could be improved by including a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

First method is for class components second is for functional components

```
   constructor (props){
        super();
        this.state = {
          quote : [],
        }
    
      this.setState({
        quote : [...this.state.quote , newObj]
      })



    const [quote, setQuote] = useState([])
    setQuote(prevState => [...prevState, newObj])
```

Answer (score -1):

I am trying to push value in an array state and set value like this and define state array and push value by map function.

```
 this.state = {
        createJob: [],
        totalAmount:Number=0
    }


 your_API_JSON_Array.map((_) => {
                this.setState({totalAmount:this.state.totalAmount += _.your_API_JSON.price})
                this.state.createJob.push({ id: _._id, price: _.your_API_JSON.price })
                return this.setState({createJob: this.state.createJob})
            })
```

Answer (score -1):

I was having a similar issue when I wanted to modify the array state
while retaining the position of the element in the array

This is a function to toggle between like and unlike:

```
    const liker = (index) =>
        setData((prevState) => {
            prevState[index].like = !prevState[index].like;
            return [...prevState];
        });
```

as we can say the function takes the index of the element in the array state, and we go ahead and modify the old state and rebuild the state tree

Comment: This is mutating the previous state, which is an anti-pattern in React.

Comment: @EmileBergeron how can we modify the element in the state while retaining the position without breaking the react rules?

Comment: You'd need to [make a shallow copy _at each_ step of nesting.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43040721/1218980)

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me to add an array within an array

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    component: prevState.component.concat(new Array(['new', 'new']))
}));
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
//get the value you want to add
const valor1 = event.target.elements.valor1.value;

//add in object 
        const todo = {
            valor1,
        }

//now you just push the new value into the state

//prevlista is the value of the old array before updating, it takes the old array value makes a copy and adds a new value

setValor(prevLista =>{
return prevLista.concat(todo) })
```

Answer (score -3):

```
//------------------code is return in typescript 

const updateMyData1 = (rowIndex:any, columnId:any, value:any) => {

    setItems(old => old.map((row, index) => {
        if (index === rowIndex) {
        return Object.assign(Object.assign({}, old[rowIndex]), { [columnId]: value });
    }
    return row;
}));
```

Answer (score -10):

This code work for me:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    this.setState({mystate: this.state.mystate.push.apply(this.state.mystate, json)})
  })
```

Comment: still, you mutate state directly

Comment: And fails to update the component's state correctly since [`.push` returns a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Return_value), not an array.