# What is the best way to add a value to an array in state

Tags: memory, state, reactjs

I have an array in state, let's say `this.state.arr`.
I want to add something to this state property, and then change some more properties.

Option 1

```
onChange(event){
    this.state.arr.push('newvalue');
    ...
    this.setState({some:'val',arr:this.state.arr})
}
```

Option 2

```
onChange(event){
    var newArr = this.state.arr;
    ...
    newArr.push('newvalue');
    ...
    this.setState({some:'val',arr:newArr})
}
```

So... I know `this.state` is supposed to be treated immutable, but is it ok to use it like in option 1 where I still set the state from it, or do I need to go with something like option 2, and thus always first making a copy in memory?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs#comment41184522_26253351 and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966438/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-mutate-a-react-state

Comment: A third option could be the best : use immutability helper provided by React : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Another simple way using concat:

```
this.setState({
  arr: this.state.arr.concat('new value')
})
```

Comment: I find this both the most expressive and least verbose method.

Comment: Changed this to the accepted answer because not only is it the last verbose, it's also the fastest solution according to jsperf

Comment: This could cause the state to get out of sync, if the setState is not called in the expected order. Better to use the setState(prevState, ...).

Answer (score 120):

For now, this is the best way.

```
this.setState(previousState => ({
    myArray: [...previousState.myArray, 'new value']
}));
```

Comment: This worked for me. It also works for prepending into the array: `this.setState((prevState) => ({
      myArray: [values, ...prevState.myArray],
    }));`

Comment: If I want 'new value' to be a parameter that I passed in. Do I simply do
```onChange = (id) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      tags: [...prevState.tags, id]
    }));
  }
```

Comment: How to add new value to a specific position in the array?

Comment: @PubuduJayasanka `setFoo(prevState => [...prevState.slice(0, pos), newItem, ...prevState.slice(pos)])` with hooks, but you can use a similar spread pattern on a specific key in a class component.

Comment: how to only add unique value?

Answer (score 67):

Both of the options you provided are the same.  Both of them will still point to the same object in memory and have the same array values.  You should treat the state object as immutable as you said, however you need to re-create the array so its pointing to a new object, set the new item, then reset the state.  Example:

```
onChange(event){
    var newArray = this.state.arr.slice();    
    newArray.push("new value");   
    this.setState({arr:newArray})
}
```

Comment: Slice will create a new shallow copy of the array, making it immutable.

Comment: @Butters FWIW, that doesn't make it immutable since objects *in* the array can still be mutated. Here it's strings so it's not an issue, but in the general case, `slice` still allows in situ updates, bypassing the normal state checking.

Answer (score 49):

If you are using ES6 syntax you can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to add new items to an existing array as a one liner.

```js
// Append an array
const newArr = [1,2,3,4]
this.setState(prevState => ({
  arr: [...prevState.arr, ...newArr]
}));

// Append a single item
this.setState(prevState => ({
  arr: [...prevState.arr, 'new item']
}));
```

Answer (score 35):

Short way with `useState` hook:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState([])
setValue([...value, newvalue])
```

Answer (score 8):

the best away now.

```
this.setState({ myArr: [...this.state.myArr, new_value] })
```

Comment: I am wondering how can I insert new value to the middle of the array instead of adding it to the end?

Answer (score 8):

For functional components with hooks

```
const [searches, setSearches] = useState([]);

// Using .concat(), no wrapper function (not recommended)
setSearches(searches.concat(query));

// Using .concat(), wrapper function (recommended)
setSearches(searches => searches.concat(query));

// Spread operator, no wrapper function (not recommended)
setSearches([...searches, query]);

// Spread operator, wrapper function (recommended)
setSearches(searches => [...searches, query]);
```

source: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-add-to-an-array-in-react-state-3d08ddb2e1dc

Comment: "setSearches(searches => searches.concat(query));
" is by far the best solution in 2021, thank you king.

Answer (score 5):

```js
onChange() {
     const { arr } = this.state;
     let tempArr = [...arr];
     tempArr.push('newvalue');
     this.setState({
       arr: tempArr
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

React hook - useState **(2022)**

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

const handleChange = (newValue) => {
  setArray((array) => [...array, newValue]);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
handleValueChange = (value) => {
      let myArr= [...this.state.myArr]
      myArr.push(value)
      this.setState({
         myArr
     })
```

This might do the work.

Answer (score 1):

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

const handleChange = (newValue) => {
  setArray((prevState) => [...prevState, newValue]);
};
```

If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value.

[setState doc.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep adding a new object to the array i've been using:

```
_methodName = (para1, para2) => {
  this.setState({
    arr: this.state.arr.concat({para1, para2})
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not directly answer your question but for the sake of those that come with states like the below

```
 state = {
    currentstate:[
     {
    id: 1 ,
    firstname: 'zinani',
    sex: 'male'

     }
    ]

 }
```

Solution

```
const new_value = {
    id: 2 ,
    firstname: 'san',
    sex: 'male'

     }
```

Replace the current state with the new value

```
 this.setState({ currentState: [...this.state.currentState, new_array] })
```