# ReactJS updating a single object inside a state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state called `this.state.devices` which is an array of `device` objects.

Say I have a function

```
updateSomething: function (device) {
    var devices = this.state.devices;
    var index = devices.map(function(d){
        return d.id;
    }).indexOf(device.id);

    if (index !== -1) {
       // do some stuff with device
       devices[index] = device;
       this.setState({devices:devices});
    }
}
```

Problem here is that every time `this.updateSomething` is called, the entire array is updated, and so the entire DOM gets re-rendered. In my situation, this causes the browser to freeze as I am calling this function pretty every second, and there are many `device` objects. However, on every call, only one or two of these devices are actually updated.

What are my options?

**EDIT**

In my exact situation, a `device` is an object that is defined as follows:

```
function Device(device) {
    this.id = device.id;
    // And other properties included
}
```

So each item in the array of `state.devices` is a specific instant of this `Device`, i.e. somewhere I'd have:

```
addDevice: function (device) {
    var newDevice = new Device(device);
    this.setState({devices: this.state.devices.push(device)});
}
```

My updated answer how on to `updateSomething`, I have:

```
updateSomething: function (device) {
    var devices = this.state.devices;
    var index = devices.map(function(d){
        return d.id;
    }).indexOf(device.id);

    if (index !== -1) {
       // do some stuff with device
       var updatedDevices = update(devices[index], {someField: {$set: device.someField}});
       this.setState(updatedDevices);
    }
}
```

Problem now is that I get an error that says cannot read the undefined value of `id`, and it is coming from the `function Device()`; it seems that a new `new Device()` is being called and the `device` is not passed to it.

Comment: There are ways to prevent rendering each time such as shouldComponentUpdate, check out this post https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/understanding-react-js-rendering. In addition, you will save some execution time if you find a way to keep the index with the device instead of mapping and searching for it each time. You are also technically changing the array in state, which should be treated as immutable, suggest using .slice() as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505064/react-js-what-is-the-best-way-to-add-a-value-to-an-array-in-state

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the react [immutability helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html).

From the docs:

**Simple push**

```
var initialArray = [1, 2, 3];
var newArray = update(initialArray, {$push: [4]}); // => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

*initialArray is still [1, 2, 3].*

So for your example you will want to do something like this:

```
if (index !== -1) {
    var deviceWithMods = {}; // do your stuff here
    this.setState(update(this.state.devices, {index: {$set: deviceWithMods }}));
}
```

Depending on how complex your `device` model is you could just 'modify' the object properties in situ:

```
if (index !== -1) {
    this.setState(update(this.state.devices[index], {name: {$set: 'a new device name' }}));
}
```

Comment: My `initialArray` is an  array of instant of an objects; i.e. I have `MyObject()` and `initialArray.push(new MyObject(object))` is how I add them. When I tried your approach, I get an error inside this object during the initialization. It says cannot read property of unknown; it is looking for a field in `object`. Is this `update` re-creating every object, and that is why it is failing?

Comment: I think you're changing the structure of the state. Inspect `devices` before your `var updatedDevices...` line and `updatedDevices` after. I think the structure will be different.

Comment: I'd still get the same error even if I comment out `this.setState`. It's the `help` function that is throwing this error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88119/discussion-between-clarkie-and-kousha).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion with react state, only store things that's really related to "state", such as things turn on, off, but of course there are exceptions.

If I were you I would pull away the array of devices as a variable and set things there, so there is what I might do:

```
var devices = [];

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    ...
    updateSomething: function (device) {

        var index = devices.map(function(d){
            return d.id;
        }).indexOf(device.id);

        if (index !== -1) {
           // do some stuff with device
           devices[index] = device;

           if(NeedtoRender) {
               this.setState({devices:devices});
           }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason above answers didn't work for me. After many trials the below did:

```
if (index !== -1) {
            let devices = this.state.devices
            let updatedDevice = {//some device}
            let updatedDevices = update(devices, {[index]: {$set: updatedDevice}})
            this.setState({devices: updatedDevices})
    }
```

And I imported `update` from `immutability-helper` based on the note from: https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html

Answer (score 0):

I solve it doing a array splice in object I wish modify, before update component state and push of object modified again.

Like example below:

```
let urls = this.state.urls;

var index = null;

for (let i=0; i < urls.length; i++){
  if (objectUrl._id == urls[i]._id){
    index = i;  
  }
}

if (index !== null){
  urls.splice(index, 1);  
}

urls.push(objectUrl);

this.setState((state) => {
  return {urls: urls}
});
```