# React: Update element of array without rerendering other array elements

Tags: arrays, reactjs, performance, immutability

Is it possible to **rerender an element** of an array, **preventing others rerender**?

**Example:** Having an array of 500 `<Card>` components and editing `<Card>` number 27 (which updates `myArray` props), I would like to **rerender only** `<Card>` number 27.

```
render = () => {
    this.props.myArray.map(card => {
        return <Cards key={card.id} ...card />
    })
}
```

In my case, `<Card>` components are a bit heavy and I would like to avoid rerendering them if they didn't individually change, but as soon as `myArray` prop changes and fires `render()` method, every single `<Card>` is being rerendered, causing some performance issues on every `<Card>` change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS updating a single object inside a state array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238679/reactjs-updating-a-single-object-inside-a-state-array)

Comment: Trying making `Card` a [`PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) or using [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've solved the issue by using `shouldComponentUpdate()` method in `Card` component as Gabriele suggested, even if `Card` component is part of the updated array, it will keep the previous rendered state if `shouldComponentUpdate()` returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

James' answer is very useful for me.
If you use React Hook, use `React.memo` and `prevProps` with `nextProps` to implement `shouldComponentUpdate()`.

(fyi: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate)

Answer (score -1):

Use memoization in your  component.If it doesn't change, the respective component is not rerendered. Googling "react memoize" will bring you a lot of nice resources.
I'd also improve your Card component to receive a Card object instead of every card attribute. Deconstructing the card object can make your life harder writing the code to memoize it.

```
render = () => {
    this.props.myArray.map(card => {
        return <Cards key={card.id} card={card} />
    })
}
```

Comment: "Use memoization in your component." This answer could be improved by explaining, or showing, what that means!