# Update an array value with useState's old values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm sure this is a simple question but I can't figure this out.

```
const [rowLabels, setRowLabels] = React.useState(['','','','','',]);
```

i figured this would work.  but it doesn't like the syntax.

```
setRowLabels(oldValues => ([
  ...oldValues,
  oldValues[position]: event.target.value
])
```

I know I can do this below, but I rather not pass down rowLabels as props to avoid the re-render.  Is there a way I can do it with just the oldValues?

```
const rowLabelsCopy = [...rowLabels];
rowLabelsCopy[position] = event.target.value;
setRowLabels(rowLabelsCopy);
```

Comment: You can't mix computed property syntax with array spread syntax unfortunately.

Comment: This should work: `setRowLabels(oldValues => oldValues.map((ov, i) => i === position ? event.target.value : ov));`

Comment: ah okay didn't realize that @PatrickRoberts.  thank you

Comment: @ChrisG ah nice little hack. it makes sense and works.  there's a typo though the last ? is supposed to be a colon.

Comment: Fixed, however there's this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121272/whats-the-best-way-to-update-an-object-in-an-array-in-reactjs

Comment: @ChrisG that one isn't about react hook usage.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I know, that's why I linked to it instead of marking this as dupe. It still shows various ways of creating a new array based on the old one, and it doesn't really matter if you call `setState` or the hook method.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setState()` function accepts a callback as you demonstrated in your first failed attempt. That callback can contain the lines in your second attempt, and allow you to use `oldValues` instead of `rowLabels`:

```
setRowLabels(oldValues => {
  const newValues = [...oldValues];
  newValues[position] = event.target.value;
  return newValues;
});
```

Or if you don't want to use an explicit return, here's a slightly less readable alternative:

```
setRowLabels(oldValues => Object.assign(
  [...oldValues],
  { [position]: event.target.value }
));
```