# How Can I use current value of a variable in somewhere else?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I change the name and age dynamiclly by creating two handlers. When I input an age it changes dynamicly. There is no problem here. But the name goes default as well. Because I defined it as a hard-coded value in 'ageChangeHandler'.But i want the name to stay like I did in the 'nameChangeHandler'. Is there something like 'currentValue' or 'lastValue' in Javascript/ES6?
I hope I explained it properly.
Thanks in advance.

I couldnt find any options like currentvalue etc.

```
    nameChangeHandler = (event) =>{ 
this.setState({
  persons: [
    {name: "Max" , age: 28},
    {name: event.target.value, age: 29},
    {name:"Arthur", age:34}
  ]
})
```

}

```
ageChangeHandler = (event) =>{
this.setState({
  persons:[
    {name: "Max" , age: 28},
    {name: "Tom", age: 29},
    {name:"Arthur", age:event.target.value}
  ]
})}
```

Lines I call handlers:

```
<Person 
      name={this.state.persons[0].name} 
      age={this.state.persons[0].age}/>
    <Person 
      name={this.state.persons[1].name} 
      age={this.state.persons[1].age}
      click={this.switchNameHandler.bind(this, "Way 2")}
      Namechanged={this.nameChangeHandler}>My hobbies: coding</Person>
    <Person 
      name={this.state.persons[2].name} 
      age={this.state.persons[2].age}
      Agechanged={this.ageChangeHandler}/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the best way to update an object in an array in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121272/whats-the-best-way-to-update-an-object-in-an-array-in-reactjs)

Comment: How/Where do you call those handlers?

Comment: It's really unclear how your code knows which object within `persons` to update. They would possibly need some kind of id.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Declared an ID for all of persons :

```
state = {
persons: [
  {id:"25343", name:"Max", age: 28},
  {id:"24323ad ", name: "Tom", age: 29},
  {id:"asdavd231", name:"Arthur", age:34}
],
```

Updated them with their ID's :

```
  ageChangeHandler = (event,id) =>{
const personIndex = this.state.persons.findIndex(p=>{
  return p.id === id;
})
const person = {
  ...this.state.persons[personIndex]
}
person.age = event.target.value;
const persons = [...this.state.persons]
persons[personIndex] = person;
this.setState({persons:persons})}
```

Rendered them in a map:

```
<div>
      {this.state.persons.map((person,index)=>{
        return <Person 
        click={() => this.deletePersonHandler(index)} //map'ten gelen index deletePersonHandler'a pareametre olarak gönderiliyor
        name={person.name} //map'in 1.parametresi. (persons'u işaret ediyor)
        age={person.age}
        key={person.id}
        nameChanged={(event)=>this.nameChangeHandler(event,person.id)}
        ageChanged={(event)=>this.ageChangeHandler(event,person.id)}/>
      })}

    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you pass a function, instead of an object to setState, you get this signature:

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
 // do something with prevState
 return { ...prevState }
});
```

allowing you to use the previous state to create the new one.

so In your case:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  return {
      ...prevState,
      persons: prevState.persons.map(person => {
        if (person.name === "Arthur") return { ...person, age: e.target.value }
        return person
     })
  }
})
```

or something like that.

Comment: Two states may be previous states. I can change before age than name. What to do then?

Comment: and I don't know how to make both states as 'prevState'.

Comment: @YusufMertÇakmak see my edit. Basically you use the spread operate (...) to fill the new state with the old one, and then make modifications accordingly. My example takes the previous persons list and prints it out but uses a map to change the value on the field you want to target.

Comment: @YusufMertÇakmak whenever you call `setState`, there will only be ONE `prevState`. You could do both modifications at once, or one after the other depending on what makes sense.

Comment: `.map` already returns a new array, there's no need to spread the result into an array.

Comment: I didn't noticed at first, but `person.age = e.target.value` is mutating the state directly. Return a new object instead. `if (condition) return { ...person, age: e.target.value };`

Answer (score -1):

You can use an index to dynamically select a user to edit and then just update its attributes:

```
nameChangeHandler = (event) => {
   const { index } = this.state;
   this.setState({
     persons: this.state.persons.map((item, j) => {
        if (j === index) {
           return {
              ...item,
              name: event.target.value,
           };
        } else {
           return item;
        }
     }),
   });
}
```

You could also create a universal function to update any number of parameters:

```
<input
    type="text"
    // Here we send a value, n index (can be from state) and the parameter to update
    onChange={(e) => { this.changeHandler(e.target.value, 0, 'name') }}
/>

changeHandler = (value, index, attr) => {
    // index is the object in the array that we want to update 
    // attr is the key
   this.setState({
     persons: this.state.persons.map((item, j) => {
        if (j === index) {
           return {
              ...item,
              [attr]: value,
           };
        } else {
           return item;
        }
     }),
   });
}
```

Comment: `persons[selectedIndex].name = event.target.value` mutates the state. [Don't mutate the state.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37755997/1218980)

Comment: Nope, not fixed. [`.slice` returns a shallow copy of the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), but you're still mutating the original object inside of it.

Comment: Removed slice, looks like it is my question now

Comment: Still mutating the state, and now losing anything else than `persons` in the state when `changeHandler` is called.

Comment: I see, I think this is why never used arrays on my state