# How to add to a nested array in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am building a Slack clone prototype. When I try to add a message to the array this.state.channels.message, it adds it instead as a new object in the array channels:

DESIRED OUTCOME

```
class App extends React.Component {
state = {
    channels : [
        { id: 1, name: 'react', messages: ['React message 1', '**DESIRED MESSAGE**']},
        { id: 2, name: 'react-router', messages: ['react-router message 1']},
    ],
```

CURRENT OUTCOME

```
class App extends React.Component {
state = {
    channels : [
        { id: 1, name: 'react', messages: ['React message 1']},
        { id: 2, name: 'react-router', messages: ['react-router message 1']},
        { id: 1, messages: '**DESIRED MESSAGE**'}
    ],
```

LOGIC TO UPDATE COMPONENT STATE

```
handleSentMessage = (value) => {
    const {selectedChannelId, selectedPersonId, channels} = this.state;

    if(this.state.selectedChannelId) {
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
          channels: [
            ...this.state.channels,
            this.state.channels[selectedChannelId-1].messages.push(value)
          ]
        }
      );
    }

    if(this.state.selectedPersonId) {
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
          people: [
            ...this.state.people,
            this.state.people[selectedPersonId-1].messages.push(value)
          ]
        }
      );
    }
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated! 
Github
https://github.com/kingdomwilks/Slack2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the best way to update an object in an array in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121272/whats-the-best-way-to-update-an-object-in-an-array-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 2):

You're  `spreading` `channels` incorrectly, cause the second statement will not overwrite anything (it's an `array` not an `object`). Use `map` and only `concat` `messages` when the `index` of `channel` is equal to `selectedChannelId - 1`

```
this.setState(prevState =>({
    channels : prevState.channels.map((channel,i) =>{
        if(i === selectedChannelId -1) return {
            ...channel,
            messages: channel.messages.concat('foo') //Now you overwrite it
        }

        return channel
    })
}))
```

You could also directly use `id` to find the correct `channel`, this way you no longer need to `selectedChannelId - 1`, just `selectedChannelId`