# React useState failing to update two way binding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to set up so that when I type a name in the input of the Person component the state in the App component is updated and in turn updates the value of a prop in Person, however it appears the state change is happening, but the prop isn't updated, can anyone help me figure out what is wrong?

**App**

```
const App = () => {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
    {id: "key1", name: "Daniel", age: "28"},
    {id: "key2", name: "John", age: "30"},
    {id: "key3", name: "Doe", age: "60"}
  ]);

  const nameChangedHandler = (id, event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    console.log(id);
    const personIndex = persons.findIndex(p => {
      return p.id === id;
    });

    const person = {
      ...persons[personIndex]
    };

    person.name = event.target.value;

    const pers = [...persons];
    persons[personIndex] = person;

    setPersons(pers);
    console.log(persons);
  };

  let people = persons.map((person, index) => {
    return (
      <Person
        name={person.name}
        key={person.id}
        age={person.age}
        changed={nameChangedHandler.bind(this, person.id)}
      />
    );
  });

  return <div className="App">{people}</div>;
};
```

**Person**

```
const person = props => (
  <div className={style.Person}>
    <p onClick={props.click}>
      I'm {props.name}, and I am {props.age}!
    </p>
    <input type="text" onChange={props.changed} value={props.name} />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the best way to update an object in an array in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121272/whats-the-best-way-to-update-an-object-in-an-array-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assigning to the wrong variable, try the following:

```
const pers = [...persons];
pers[personIndex] = person;
```

And it should work as expected. Since you were updating your state object **`persons`** instead of the object you cloned **`pers`**, which you used to set the state, your console log was showing the expected output but your state wasn't being updated properly.

Check this working **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4fv8ye)**

Comment: FWIW, the OP can also get rid of the `bind` by using `onChange={e => changed(id, e)}` in `Person` (where `changed `is the destructured prop). E.g., and then just use `changed={nameChangedHandler}`. But to do that, they have to pass `id` to `Person` (rather than just using `id` as `key`).

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I would use a simple `map` function to change the name of the particular person.

Inside `nameChangedHandler` function:

```
const updatedPersons = persons
   .map((person) => person.id === id ? {...person, name: event.target.value} : person);
```

and then update the local state

```
setPersons(updatedPersons);
```

It should work as expected.