# Why the value in this array (apparently) changes immediately

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I couldn't find any similar question, I don't know what could be happening there, (and maybe could be something stupid) but I haven't found any clue about what could be happening.

I have this array:

```js
const superVillains = [
  { value: '1', label: 'Thanos' },
  { value: '2', label: 'The Joker' },
  { value: '3', label: 'Ultron', disabled: true },
  { value: '4', label: 'The Riddler' },
  { value: '5', label: 'Lex Luthor' },
  { value: '6', label: 'Green Goblin' },
  { value: '7', label: 'Bain', disabled: true },
  { value: '8', label: 'The Penguin' },
  { value: '9', label: 'Doctor Octopus' },
  { value: '10', label: 'Poison Ivy' },
  { value: '11', label: 'Magneto' },
  { value: '12', label: 'Mr. Glass' },
  { value: '13', label: 'General Zod' },
  { value: '14', label: 'Red Skull', disabled: true },
  { value: '15', label: 'Baron Von Zemo' }
];
```

I copied this array into another called `optionsState` in a react state

```js
const [optionsState, setOptionsState] = useState(superVillains);
```

and applied the following operations:

```js
const index = 0; 
optionsState[index]['selected'] = true; 
console.log(optionsState[index]['selected']);
console.log(optionsState[index]);
console.log(optionsState);
```

This is the result in console:

[image: Console redult]

In the first console output it seems that the selected value is true as it should, the same for the second console output, but without changing nothing in the code the third console output shows that the selected value is false.

the question is: Why does the `selected` value apparently changes without applying any operations on it (besides a console log statement)?

If a place another

```js
console.log(optionsState[index]);
```

after the last console log it will show the same as before:

```js
{value: "1", label: "Thanos", selected: true}
```

so I don't know if it is an issue with the browser or an issue with the react states or an issue with me.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: what are the values of option , element ?

Comment: just do a fully running demo with https://stackblitz.com/fork/react or explain every variable

Comment: Works as expected with the code provided... Do not have the same issue...

Comment: @RenaldoBalaj option and element are not relevant, I edited to make that clear. Also I will give a try to the tool you posted, thank you!

Comment: i gave you the answer, careful of other answers they are mutating the object

Comment: for more questions, comment at the answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Whats the best way to update an object in an array in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121272/whats-the-best-way-to-update-an-object-in-an-array-in-reactjs)

Comment: Hi everyone, I was not trying to update the state, I mean, eventually I will update the state and for sure I will do it as you suggested, but in this case taking a look to the variable not as updating the state but just as a single array it shouldn't change the value? as far as I know if you change a value in a state it will change but you shouldn't do it like that because it will be changed when the setOptionsState function is called. but that's another concern. My question was not about how to change the state (I know there a lot of example about how to do this)

Comment: @FabianMerchan you were mutating the state, you should never do   stateX = 'x' , always  setStateX('x').
Because you did **that equal thing**, all of this nonsense happened, try to update the state in the same way as in my answer :)

Comment: [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37755997/1218980)

Answer (score 2):

Now that you edited your question, I get it :)

You are mutating your state, and react is based in *immutability* (google for more), a quick fix would be :

```
setOptionsState(prevState => {
  const oldOptions = [...prevState.optionsState];
  oldOptions[index] = { ...oldOptions[index] , selected: true };
  return { oldOptions };
})
```

Comment: It's spelled *immutability* and no need for caps.

Comment: if you want to highlight the word like that then why not.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mjftz7 take a look ok this I tried to do same and in this fiddle it works as expected, it changes the selected value in all the console log statements (even when I know that you should not change the state like that) I am starting to think that this is an issue related only to my project and not as a general question.

Comment: it may change it correctly in console.logs , but is it stable? nah 
Try printing that array in the screen with .map , and when you change it in your way the printed array won't change.

Comment: @RenaldoBalaj There are typos in your code example. `const oldOptions =[...prevState.optionsState];` since it's an array.

Comment: I tried your answer (and I know that it is the correct way to update the state) but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
optionsState[index]['selected'] = true;
```

You should not mutate state like this. If you want to add a new attribute to the state, you should do it using the function provided, in your case it is going to be `setOptionsState`.
The easiest way to achieve this should be something like this:

```
setOptionsState(prevState => {
  const oldOptions = [...prevState.optionsState];
  oldOptions[index] = { ...oldOptions[index], selected: true };
  return { oldOptions };
})
```

Please try this approach and see if it's any different (I hope so!)

Comment: you are mutating the oldOptions[index] , ... is not enough when objects inside arrays

Comment: Your explanation is good, but the example implemention is incorrect unfortunately.

Comment: @RenaldoBalaj well thanks, I'll update the answer and will learn myself today!

Comment: @Konstantin just making sure you will learn it the right way :P  
 if "select" would be an object(key of an object) inside that oldOptions you would need spread operator ... again to modify its value :)

Answer (score 1):

As already said, you're directly mutating the state, which is a bad idea in React. To properly update the state use functional form of `setState` plus `map`:

```
const index = 0;

setOptionsState(options => {
  return options.map((option, i) => {
    if (index === i) {
      return {
        ...option,
        selected: true
      }
    }
    return option;
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the value of `optionsState` use `setOptionsState` because the state value is updated after the refresh if you dont use `setOptionsState`.