# How to fix dispatch function calling twice each time after clicking button in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dispatch, react-context

I have been working on a simple program where I have an array of posts and want to update the individual values of each post object. For this case, I want to update the number of 'likes' a post has when I click on the like button.

Here is the code I have for the reducer:

```
export function postReducer(state, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_LIKES':
            return (
                state.map(post => post.id === action.id ? {...post, likes: post.likes+=1, ...post } : {...post })
            )
        default:
            return state   
    }
}
```

Here is the code I have for the button event calling dispatch when clicked:

```
export default function PostItem({ post }) {
    const { dispatch } = useContext(PostContext);

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="post-stats">
                <button className="post-like-button" onClick={() => dispatch({
                    type: 'UPDATE_LIKES', id: post.id
                })}>{post.likes}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The issue I'm having is that whenever I click the like button, the 'likes' value increments by 1 only after the first click and then increments by 2 each click afterwards. I want the like button to increment 'likes' by 1 every time I click it. I have tried to figure it out myself and find a solution online but had no luck. All help is appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Whats the best way to update an object in an array in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121272/whats-the-best-way-to-update-an-object-in-an-array-in-reactjs)

Comment: Specifically, the following: `state.map(post => post.id === action.id ? {...post, likes: post.likes + 1 } : post)` had 2 errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be mutating state in your reducer by using `+=`, which may lead to unexpected behavior. Remove this and the unnecessary spread operators and the behavior should be cleaned up.

```js
export function postReducer(state, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_LIKES':
            return (
                state.map(post => post.id === action.id ? {...post, likes: post.likes + 1 } : post)
            )
        default:
            return state   
    }
}
```