# How to change in setState specific value in array of objects onClick event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, use-state

I want to change class active in my local state on click and change inActive to all other objects in the state.

```js
const [jobType, setJobType] = useState([
        {
            "class": "active",
            "type": "All Jobs"
        },
        {
            "class": "inActive",
            "type": "My Jobs"
        },
        {
            "class": "inActive",
            "type": "Saved Jobs"
        },
    ])

const jobTypeClick = (event, item) =>{
        alert("I am clicked")
        console.log(item)
        setJobType(...jobType, jobType.class:"active")
    }

const jobTypes = jobType.map((data) => {
        return (
            <p className={data.class+" mb-0 px-3 secondary-font fs-16"} key={data.type} onClick={event => jobTypeClick(event, data.type)}>{data.type}</p>
        )
    })
```

Comment: `jobType.class:"active"` looks like a syntax error

Comment: Duplicate: [React: how to update state.item\[1\] in state using setState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537299/react-how-to-update-state-item1-in-state-using-setstate)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update state with usestate in an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62918710/how-to-update-state-with-usestate-in-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1):

This solution will work, but keep in mind that `type` should be unique

```
const jobTypeClick = (event, item) => {
    setJobType(jobType.map(t => {
        return { ...t, "class": (t.type === item) ? "active" : "inActive" }
    }))
}
```

Otherwise, you can pass the element index to the function this assures you uniqueness within an `Array`. Another nice feature is to pass a callback to `set`. The callback will receive the latest value allowing you to use this function even within async logic.

```
const jobTypeClick = (event, index) => {
    setJobType(current => current.map((t, ix) => ({ ...t, "class": (ix === index) ? "active" : "inActive" }));
}
```

Comment: Don't just dump code. Explain what you've changed and why you've made that change.

Comment: Too fast, I was still editing ;)

Comment: You don't have to be first to post. Next time take time to write a decent considered answer.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly for me, just a newbie question from my side. Why do we've to map? can't we just setState using the previous state clone and change value?

Comment: Yes, but you need to make a deep copy (copy the array but also the elements) to prevent altering elements present in the previous state. Map is used as we want a new array and we are creating a new object too (see the spread operation { ... t }

Comment: @MuhammadAzfarAslam If you believe this answers your question please mark the answer as correct ;)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I already marked it correct. Unfortunately, my vote doesn't count due to my account reputation.

Answer (score -1):

What you are doing in setJobType is Wrong
setJobType(...jobType, jobType.class:"active")
To setJobType you need to pass an array with updated value

You need to loop all the jobTyes and make class "inActive" to all objects
and make the one with same click index to "active"

You can use the below code
I have added a third argument to read the index from click element
and looping all jobTypes and make the correct one to active and other to inActive

```
const [jobType, setJobType] = useState([
        {
            "class": "active",
            "type": "All Jobs"
        },
        {
            "class": "inActive",
            "type": "My Jobs"
        },
        {
            "class": "inActive",
            "type": "Saved Jobs"
        },
    ])

const jobTypeClick = (event, item, i ) =>{
        alert("I am clicked")
        console.log(item)
        let prevJobType = [...jobType];
        prevJobType.map((d,index) => {...d, class: index == i ? "active" : "inActive")
        setJobType(prevJobType)
    }

const jobTypes = jobType.map((data, i) => {
        return (
            <p className={data.class+" mb-0 px-3 secondary-font fs-16"} key={data.type} onClick={event => jobTypeClick(event, data.type, i)}>{data.type}</p>
        )
    })
```

Comment: Don't just dump code. Explain what you've changed and why you've made that change.

Comment: The following line of code `prevJobType.map(d => d.class = "inActive")` is changing the state in-place, as the `prevJobType` is only a shallow copy

Comment: I have added teh description, thanks @Andy

Comment: prevJobType is already a copy.

Comment: @sojin Using `[...jobType]` only makes it a shallow copy, so the objects within `jobType` aren't copied which means they're still pointing to the same object references that the original state was, so you'll end up modifying the original state when you do. `d.class = "inActive"`, as `d` is referring to an object from the original state as it isn't a copy

Comment: OK thanks. will update my answer,

Comment: Updated it in answer, Thankyou