# How to STOP React state from being modified when modifying array set to state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

Trust you are having a great day!

I'm running into a serious issue with React. I have a state which holds an array. In a function I copy the state into a new variable. When I modify this newly defined variable it also updates the state which is not what I want.

Example:

```
const [arrayState, setArrayState] = useState(
    [
        {
            id: 'ID_1'
            text: 'item 1',
        },
        {
            id: 'ID_2'
            text: 'item 2',
        },
        {
            id: 'ID_3'
            text: 'item 3',
        },
        {
            id: 'ID_4'
            text: 'item 4',
        },
    ]
);

const myFunction = () => {
    let myVariable = [...arrayState];

    myVariable[1].text = 'myVariable item 2'; // This is modifying arrayState as well which is wrong

};
```

I only want `myVariable` to be modified and not my state (`arrayState`) as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update state with usestate in an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62918710/how-to-update-state-with-usestate-in-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: or [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#sect1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) to make a deep clone of the array of objects.

```js
let myVariable = structuredClone(arrayState);
```

Alternatively, a solution that only works for this specific data structure:

```js
let myVariable = arrayState.map(o => ({...o}));
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with primitive and reference values. Arrays and objects do not store values, but they refer to addresses in memory where values ​​are stored. A simple example:

```
const func = () => {
    // Same memory reference
    const temp = arrayState;
    temp[1] = "4";
    setAttayState(temp);
}
```

above code does not re-render because reference of the value has not changed.

You have to assign new reference address like this:

```
const func = () => {

    // Create new reference
    const temp = [...arrayState];
    temp[1] = "4";
    setAttayState(temp);
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate your comment! My issue is not updating the state, however it is that when I update `myVariable` that `arrayState` is unexpectedly being modified as well

Comment: On my end `let myVariable = [...arrayState];` is also changing `arrayState` which should not be happening unless I use `setArrayState();`

Comment: That is related to shallow copy, in this case you have to totally create new arry in your method. like let newArray : any[] = [];

Comment: @John When you say "`myVariable = [...arrayState]` is also changing `arrayState`" it confuses people. That **can't** change `arrayState`, which is changed **after** that when you modify an object property in `myVariable`. **Then** an object in `arrayState` is changed because it's the same object that's in `myVariable`, because `myVariable` and `arrayState` are both arrays *(but different arrays)* of the same objects.