# trying to update an existing object in array of objects using react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I have array of objects and the format is like this

```
 addedOpaqueMaterials = [{
            conductivity: 1
            density: 1
            id: "1"
            ......
            ......
         },
         {
             conductivity: 2
             density: 1
             id: "2",
             ......
             ......
         }]
```

and from the react state i am getting updated object with the `id= 2` like as this below,

```
{
    conductivity: 4
    density: 23
    id: "2",
    ......
    ......
}
```

and i am looking to update the object in main array with these values, what could be the best way to update, below is the code related to that.

```
const handleDrawerSubmit = values => {
   const addedOpaqueMaterials = formValues.constructionSet?.opaqueMaterials; // array of objects

   const updatedMaterial = addedOpaqueMaterials.find(i => i.id === values?.opaqueMaterial?.id);
   // values?.opaqueMaterial is having updated object
    
   // Object.assign(updatedMaterial, values.opaqueMaterial); getting an error      
};
```

Now I would like to merge `values.Opaquematerial` object into `addedOpaqueMaterials` which is array of objects, what could be the best way to achieve this?

Many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Whats the best way to update an object in an array in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121272/whats-the-best-way-to-update-an-object-in-an-array-in-reactjs)

Comment: See also [Correct modification of state arrays in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26253351/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.find`, use `.findIndex` first, so that you can replace the object in the array with the new object. (Remember not to use `Object.assign` in React when the first parameter is stateful, because that'd result in a state mutation)

You should also check that all of these objects exist first before trying to update.

```
if (!formValues.constructionSet || !values || !values.opaqueMaterial) {
  return;
}
const newMat = values.opaqueMaterial;
const index = addedOpaqueMaterials.findIndex(mat => mat.id === newMat.id);
if (index === -1) {
  // Add to the end of the existing array:
  const newOpaqueMaterials = [
    ...addedOpaqueMaterials,
    newMat
  ];
  // put newOpaqueMaterials into state
} else {
  // Replace the object in the state array with the new object:
  const newOpaqueMaterials = [
    ...addedOpaqueMaterials.slice(0, index),
    newMat,
    ...addedOpaqueMaterials.slice(index + 1)
  ];
  // put newOpaqueMaterials into state
}
```

Comment: You should modify your variable declarations. Declaring inside the `if` block will make the array unavailable where it's needed. EDIT: Sorry, I did not see your comment. Seems kind of weird, to have the same operation in an `if` and `else`, but it is viable.

Comment: @Andrew OP didn't show how he's updating the state, or if he's using hooks or class components. He'll probably be able to replace the occurrences of `// put newOpaqueMaterials into state` with `setMaterials(newOpaqueMaterials)` or the equivalent, which doesn't require modifying the scope used in the answer.

Comment: The construction of the new array is somewhat different depending on whether the index is -1 or not. Yeah, I guess you could use the conditional operator to shove it all into a single statement (or use `let`, ew), but I really think separate blocks makes the intent of the code clearer.

Comment: Using `let` from time to time isn't the worst thing in the world. Another option is a `do` expression, but that would only be an answer if you assume they have the babel config for it.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a regular algorithm challenge. No need to otherthink it. The only requirement that react demands out of you is that it needs to be a new array. `Array#map` works perfectly fine.

```js
const materialExists = addedOpaqueMaterials.some(({id}) => id === values?.opaqueMaterial?.id)
let updatedMaterial
if (materialExists) {
    updatedMaterial = addedOpaqueMaterials.map(material => {
        if (material.id === values?.opaqueMaterial?.id) {
            return values.opaqueMaterial
        }
        return material
    })
} else {
    updatedMaterial = [...addedOpaqueMaterials, values.opaqueMaterial]
}
```