# React shallow copy still triggers re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

From what I learnt about React, you should not mutate any objects otherwise React doesn't know to re-render, for example, the following example should not trigger re-render in the UI when button is clicked on:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App({ input }) {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(input);

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <MyItem item={item}/>
      ))}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setItems((prevItems) => {
            return prevItems.map((item) => {
              if (item.id === 2) {
                item.name = Math.random();
              }
              return item;
            });
          });
        }}
      >
        Update wouldn't work due to shallow copy
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function MyItem ({item}) {
  const name = item.name
  return <p>{name}</p>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App
    input={[
      { name: "apple", id: 1 },
      { name: "banana", id: 2 }
    ]}
  />,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

You can try above code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-deepshallow-copy-of-array-0dfev?file=/index.js)

And the correct way to update the array of objects should be like below (other ways of deep copying would work too)

```
 setItems((prevItems) => {
    return prevItems.map((item) => {
               if (item.id === 2) {
                   # This way we return a deepcopy of item
                   return {...item, name: Math.random()}
               }
               return item;
            });
});
```

Why does the 1st version works fine and the UI is updated right away even though I'm just updating the original item object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render happens due to `.map` that creates new array. If you do something like `prev[1].name = "x"; return prev;`  in your hook, this will not perform an update. Per [reactjs doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) on `setState` with function argument:

> If your update function returns the exact same value as the current
> state, the subsequent rerender will be skipped completely.

*Update*.

Yes, speaking of parent-child interaction, `item` would be the same (by reference), but the child `props` would differ. You have `MyItem({ item })` and this `item` is being destructured from `props`, say `MyItem(props)`, and this `props` changes because of the parent source is changed.

So each time you `map` the list, you explicitly ask the parent to render its children, and the fact that some (or all) of the child's param is not changed does not matter. To prove this you may remove any params from the child component:

```
  {items.map(() => ( <MyItem /> ))}
```

```
function MyItem () {
  return <p>hello</p>
}
```

`MyItem` will be invoked each time you perform `items` update via state hook. And its `props` will always be different from the previous version.

Comment: hmm, I know map returns a new array, but that's enough for triggering re-render of all child components? Why did I read many posts about deep copying each object inside the array is also required? For example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121272/whats-the-best-way-to-update-an-object-in-an-array-in-reactjs

Comment: @Arch1tect Please take a look, I expanded the answer taking into account parent-child issue. Also, I think, you probably need to update the codesandbox demo, as it does not include child component for now.

Answer (score 0):

if your setItem setting a `new object`, your page with a state change will re-render
in your logic, you performed a shallow copy, which:

- a shallow copy created a new object, and copy everything of the 1st level from old object.

Shallow copy and deep copy also created a new object, they both trigger a re-render in React.

The different of shallow copy and deep copy is: from 2nd level of the old object, shallow copy remains the same objects, which deep copy will create new objects in all level.