# Reactjs array mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this function:

```
setNotActiveWalletsList = () => {
   
    const { GetAccounts } = this.props;
    let shallowCopyOfWalletsArray = [...GetAccounts]  
    const notActive = shallowCopyOfWalletsArray.filter(user => user.active !== true);


    let newArr = notActive.map(item => {

      return decryptAccountInformation(item).then(result => {
          !result.address ? null : item.address = result.address
      })
   
    });

    this.setState({ onlyNotActive: newArr });
  }
```

GetAccounts is an array of objects

The issue is, One of my colleagues have told me that I am mutating the array with this line:

```
 !result.address ? null : item.address = result.address
```

But I don't really understand why is this considered a mutation? I am sure I created a copy of the original array and modified it.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this, please?

Comment: It’s not good practice to mutate an array while mapping over it because it could have unexpected outputs.

Comment: Could you suggest any workaround?

Comment: You created a shallow copy of the array, not the items, and you're then mutating the items.

Comment: You're also setting an array of promises as the `onlyNotActive` state, it that really intended?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Whats the best way to update an object in an array in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121272/whats-the-best-way-to-update-an-object-in-an-array-in-reactjs)

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(GetAccounts))` will give you new references. Assuming the `GetAccounts` only contains serializable types.

Comment: @JonathanHamel that's mostly a hack for deep-copy, it's really not needed here. (It's really never needed IMO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spread syntax just does a one level closing of the object or array. Any object or array which is more than one level deep will still have the same reference. Hence when you using `notActive` array `items`, you are essentially working on the same reference that was inside `GetAccounts`

The correct way to update is to return the cloned and updated reference from within the map function and using `Promise.all` to also handle the async call

```
setNotActiveWalletsList = () => {
   
    const { GetAccounts } = this.props;
    let shallowCopyOfWalletsArray = [...GetAccounts]  
    const notActive = shallowCopyOfWalletsArray.filter(user => user.active !== true);


    let promises = notActive.map(item => {

      return decryptAccountInformation(item).then(result => {
          return !result.address ? item : {...item, address: result.address}
      })
   
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then(newArr => this.setState({ onlyNotActive: newArr }));
    
  }
```

Comment: @EmileBergeron Thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer

Comment: I am very thankful for you answer and explanation!