# How to update an object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React app retrieves a list of Items from a database and stores them in state, like this:

```
Client.getListOfItems(url)
.then((itemList) => {        // itemList is an array of Items
    setItemList(itemList);   // Declared as [itemList, setItemList] = useState([]);
});
```

Now I want to modify each `Item` in `itemList` by adding in some sub-data.  Each Item has the key 'userID'; I want to loop over each item to get the corresponding userID, and then copy that into the Item object.  Then the saved itemList should contain a list of Items, each of which has the property 'user'.

So far I have:

```
Client.getListOfItems()
.then((itemList) => {        // itemList is an array of Items

  const newItemList = itemList.forEach((item) => {
    Client.getUser(item.userID)
    .then((user) => {
       let newItem = {...item, users: user};
       return newItem;
    })
  })

  setItemList(newItemList);

});
```

but `newItemList` is undefined at the point when I'm trying to call `setItemList`.  How do I achieve what I need here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactjs array mutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66585490/reactjs-array-mutation) See how [Shubham Khatri uses `Promise.all` and `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66586090/1218980).

Comment: Thank you! I think that's what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your list into array of promises, and then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all promises to resolve, and then use one  more `then` to set the state:

```js
Client.getListOfItems()
  .then((itemList) => {
    const newItemListPromises = itemList.map((item) => {
      return Client.getUser(item.userID).then((user) => {
        let newItem = { ...item, users: user };
        return newItem;
      });
    });
    return Promise.all(newItemsListPromises);
  })
  .then((list) => setItemList(list));
```

Use with caution, since if at least one promise will fail, `Promise.all` will also fail. Don't forget to [`catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) your errors

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't come across Promise.all before, but that looks like exactly what I need.