# React JS add dynamic object values from FORM to objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, ecmascript-6

I have array of objects where i need to an key value

State :

```
const [row, setRow] = useState([{ nameofthework: "", schedulerefNo: "", unitprice: "", qty: "", uom: "", gst: "", total: "" }]);
```

The form input change function

```
const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...row];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setRow(list);
    console.log(row);  // Prints out the each row object into and array of objects
};

const handleQty = (e) => {
    const scheduleNumberForQuantity = e.target.value;
    projectScheduleNumber?.filter((v) => {
        if(v["Schedule No"] === scheduleNumberForQuantity ) {
            setScheduleQuantity(v["LOA Qty"]); // return only integer example 1000
        }
    })
}
```

My Form

```
<Form.Control as="select" name="schedulerefNo" value={x.schedulerefNo} onChange={e => {handleInputChange(e, i); handleQty(e)}}>
```

How to add handleQty value to row state ?

Answer (score 0):

Same way as in the handleInputChange?

```
const list = [...row];
const item = list[index];
if (item) {
  item.qty = e.target.value;
  setRow(list);
}
```

Also in React it is not good practice to mutate data. You should rather create new list with the updated item.

[Whats the best way to update an object in an array in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121272/whats-the-best-way-to-update-an-object-in-an-array-in-reactjs)

Comment: how do push the new object key value inside the row object ?

Comment: Just add it to your's item before calling setState (setRow) function. e.g. `item.myNewProperty = true`

Comment: Or better is to create a new object `const newItem = { ...item, myNewProperty: true };` and than replace it in list `list[index] = newItem;`