# Two similar react functions produce Inconsistent Results in rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-fullstack

This function works properly and the component rerenders

```
  handleRemove = (e) => {
//console.log(e);
const arrayCopy = this.state.scanlist.filter((row) => row.ref + row.lot !== e.ref + e.lot);
this.setState({ scanlist: arrayCopy });};
```

This function changes the state but the component does not rerender

```
  handleAdd = (e) => {
//console.log(e);
const index = this.state.scanlist.findIndex((row) => row.ref === e.ref && row.lot === e.lot);
let scancopy = this.state.scanlist;
scancopy[index].qty = scancopy[index].qty + 1;
console.log(scancopy);
this.setState({ scanlist: scancopy });};
```

Does anyone see the issue? Mutation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Whats the best way to update an object in an array in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121272/whats-the-best-way-to-update-an-object-in-an-array-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.filter` to remove an element from an array is pretty standard, but in the second handler yes, you've a state object mutation.

```
handleAdd = (e) => {
  const index = this.state.scanlist.findIndex((row) => row.ref === e.ref && row.lot === e.lot);
  let scancopy = this.state.scanlist;
  scancopy[index].qty = scancopy[index].qty + 1; // <-- state object mutation
  this.setState({ scanlist: scancopy });
};
```

You should shallow copy the `scanlist` array ***and*** the element that is being updated. `Array.prototype.map` is a common method to shallow copy the state array, and spreading the object properties of the element that needs to be updated shallow copies it. Anytime you are updating any nested state objects you should shallow copy the parent object.

```
handleAdd = (e) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    scanlist: prevState.scanlist.map(
      (row) => row.ref === e.ref && row.lot === e.lot ? {
        ...row,
        qty: row.qty + 1,
      } : row)
  }));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first approach filter method returns new list, whereas in the second approach it is just referencing to state array.

Try shallow copy in second approach,

```
let scancopy = [...this.state.scanlist]
```

Or

Simple deep copy approach,

```
let scancopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.scanlist));
```

Comment: This first method still mutates the array elements, they need to be copied as well. The second, using JSON to serialize/deserialize is very anti-pattern.

Comment: This improved the stability but there was an still an issue with one of the nested components that use this data.

Comment: Oh. Does shallow copy still mutates the array elements ? @DrewReese. I have edited the solution to deep copy as well, thanks.

Comment: @DrewReese Do you think my first function needs changing also or is that correct in JS/React?

Comment: Shallow copy of the array just means you've a new array reference, but the array elements are still references to the objects of the copied array.

Comment: True ! Thanks. Got confused over there.