# Cart Array in useState won't update with onClick Event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I just began learning React and learning how to use Context Api. I am trying to update my cart when user clicks the add to cart button from the product page but for some reason it won't update the state.

Here is my code:

context api:

```js
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { detailProduct, storeProducts } from './data';

const ProductContext = createContext();

const ProviderContext = ({ children }) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState({
    product: [],
    detailsProduct: detailProduct,
    cart: [],
    modalOpen: false,
    modalProduct: detailProduct,
  });

  const { product, detailsProduct, cart, modalOpen, modalProduct } = products;

  const newProducts = () => {
    let tempProducts = [];
    storeProducts.forEach((item) => {
      const singleItem = { ...item };
      tempProducts = [...tempProducts, singleItem];
    });
    setProducts({
      ...products,
      product: tempProducts,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    newProducts();
  }, []);

  const getItem = (id) => {
    const singleProduct = product.find((item) => item.id === id);
    return singleProduct;
  };

  const handleDetail = (id) => {
    const newProduct = getItem(id);
    setProducts({ ...products, detailsProduct: newProduct });
  };

  const addToCart = (id) => {
    let tempProducts = [...product];
    const index = tempProducts.indexOf(getItem(id));
    const cartProduct = tempProducts[index];
    cartProduct.inCart = true;
    cartProduct.count = 1;
    const price = cartProduct.price;
    cartProduct.total = price;

    setProducts({
      ...products,
      product: tempProducts,
      cart: [...cart, cartProduct],
    });

    console.log(products);
  };

  const openModal = (id) => {
    const product = getItem(id);
    setProducts({ ...products, modalProduct: product, modalOpen: true });
    console.log(products);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setProducts({ ...products, modalOpen: false });
  };

  return (
    <ProductContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...products,
        handleDetail: handleDetail,
        addToCart: addToCart,
        openModal: openModal,
        closeModal: closeModal,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ProductContext.Provider>
  );
};

const ConsumerContext = ProductContext.Consumer;

export { ProviderContext, ConsumerContext };
```

My product page:

```js
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConsumerContext } from '../Context';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Product = ({ product }) => {
  const { id, title, img, price, inCart } = product;

  return (
    <ProductWrapper className='col-9 mx-auto col-md-6 col-lg-3 my-3'>
      <div className='card'>
        <ConsumerContext>
          {(value) => (
            <div
              className='img-container p-5'
              onClick={() => value.handleDetail(id)}
            >
              <Link to='/details'>
                <img src={img} alt='product' className='card-img-top' />
              </Link>
              <button
                className='cart-btn'
                disabled={inCart ? true : false}
                onClick={() => {
                  value.addToCart(id);
                  value.openModal(id);
                }}
              >
                {inCart ? (
                  <p className='text-capitalize mb-0' disabled>
                    in cart
                  </p>
                ) : (
                  <i className='fas fa-cart-plus'></i>
                )}
              </button>
            </div>
          )}
        </ConsumerContext>
        <div className='card-footer d-flex justify-content-between'>
          <p className='align-self-center mb-0'>{title}</p>
          <h5 className='tex-blue font-italic mb-0'>
            <span className='mr-1'>$</span>
            {price}
          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ProductWrapper>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

I am also using the onClick element on the product details page which for some reason works while the one on the product page doesn't work. here is the product details code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ConsumerContext } from '../Context';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ButtonContainer } from './Button';

const ProductDetails = () => {
  return (
    <ConsumerContext>
      {(value) => {
        const { id, company, img, info, price, title, inCart } =
          value.detailsProduct;

        return (
          <div className='container py-5'>
            {/* {title} */}
            <div className='row'>
              <div className='col-10 mx-auto text-center text-slanted text-blue my-5'>
                <h1>{title}</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
            {/* {title} */}
            {/* {product info} */}
            <div className='row'>
              <div className='col-10 mx-auto col-md-6 my3'>
                <img src={img} alt='product' className='img-fluid' />
              </div>
              {/* {product text} */}
              <div className='col-10 mx-auto col-md-6 my3 text-capitalize'>
                <h2>model : {title}</h2>
                <h4 className='text-title text-uppercase text-muted mt-3 mb-2'>
                  made by : <span className='text-uppercase'>{company}</span>
                </h4>
                <h4 className='text-blue'>
                  <strong>
                    price : <span>$</span>
                    {price}
                  </strong>
                </h4>
                <p className='text-capitalize font-weight-bold mt-3 mb-0'>
                  about product:
                </p>
                <p className='text-muted lead'>{info}</p>
                {/* {buttons} */}
                <div>
                  <Link to='/'>
                    <ButtonContainer>back to products</ButtonContainer>
                  </Link>
                  <ButtonContainer
                    cartButton
                    disabled={inCart ? true : false}
                    onClick={() => {
                      value.addToCart(id);
                      // value.openModal(id);
                    }}
                  >
                    {inCart ? 'in cart' : 'add to cart'}
                  </ButtonContainer>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }}
    </ConsumerContext>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Whats the best way to update an object in an array in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121272/whats-the-best-way-to-update-an-object-in-an-array-in-reactjs)

Comment: Spreading `[...products]` only does a shallow copy, so `cartProduct.inCart = true;` is mutating the state.

Comment: Also, the console log after `setProduct` will never show the change as [state updates happens asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/1218980) (unchanged until the next render).

Comment: Thanks for the help. My problem isn't solved yet. I use the react addon for chrome to see that the Cart state actually gets updated from the product details page when i click add to cart from that page but doesn't get updated when i click the button from the product list page.