# How to change data in a nested JSON by javascript lodash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

for example, i have a JSON file like this

```
{
  "employees": [
    { "name": "Ram", "email": "ram@gmail.com", "age": 23 },
    { "name": "Shyam", "email": "shyam23@gmail.com", "age": 28 },
    { "name": "John", "email": "john@gmail.com", "age": 33 },
    { "name": "Bob", "email": "bob32@gmail.com", "age": 33 }
  ]
}
```

Now i want to create a new array that same as this, but modded specific value, like if age is 33 then change to 1, like

```
{
  "employees": [
    { "name": "Ram", "email": "ram@gmail.com", "age": 23 },
    { "name": "Shyam", "email": "shyam23@gmail.com", "age": 28 },
    { "name": "John", "email": "john@gmail.com", "age": 1 },
    { "name": "Bob", "email": "bob32@gmail.com", "age": 1 }
  ]
}
```

How can i do this with lodash or javascript array ?
Thank you guy a lots

Comment: Since you've tagged the question with React, does this answer your question? [Whats the best way to update an object in an array in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121272/whats-the-best-way-to-update-an-object-in-an-array-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create a new array you need to take care not to modify the existing elements of the array.  You can do this in a number of ways, however because your data is multiple levels, using functions like `Array.map()` or the Spread operator (`...`) can be problematic.  You need to copy the data first.  One way is using `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` to create the copy, then modify it using an Array maniulation method (`.map()`, `.reduce()`, `.forEach()`, etc) to modify the data.

```js
var data = {
  employees: [
    { name: "Ram", email: "ram@gmail.com", age: 23 },
    { name: "Shyam", email: "shyam23@gmail.com", age: 28 },
    { name: "John", email: "john@gmail.com", age: 33 },
    { name: "Bob", email: "bob32@gmail.com", age: 33 }
  ]
}

var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
copy.employees.map( elem => { elem.age = elem.age==33?1:elem.age; return elem } )
console.log(copy)
```

Comment: It's unclear if OP uses React or not, but if he is, the JSON parsing trick is a bad practice as it would cause a re-render of everything instead of just the changed elements.

Answer (score 0):

Map is the good way to do it, but if it is nested somewhere in an object you can also add the spread operator:

```js
const object = { 
  employees: [
    { name: "Ram", email: "ram@gmail.com", age: 23 },
    { name: "Shyam", email: "shyam23@gmail.com", age: 28 },
    { name: "John", email: "john@gmail.com", age: 33 },
    { name: "Bob", email: "bob32@gmail.com", age: 33 },
  ]
}
const employees = object.employees.map((employee) => {
  employee.age = employee.age === 33 ? 1 : employee.age; 
  return employee
})
const newObject = {
  ...object,
  employees: employees
}

console.log(newObject)
```

Comment: Your map function is copying object references into the new array, not a new object.  It's mutating the original object.  Spread also has this behavior since it is also a shallow copy

Answer (score -1):

as @Tibrogargan mentioned this answer is not good if you need to do a deep copy because map function doing a shallow copy
more about that and more ways to do deep copy you can see here [https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-deep-copy-objects-and-arrays-in-javascript-7c911359b089#:~:text=4.,objects%20are%20not%20actually%20cloned](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-deep-copy-objects-and-arrays-in-javascript-7c911359b089#:%7E:text=4.,objects%20are%20not%20actually%20cloned).

it might be not good for you Please check Tibrogargan answer

you can use map method of Javascript

```
  let data = {
    employees: [
      { name: "Ram", email: "ram@gmail.com", age: 23 },
      { name: "Shyam", email: "shyam23@gmail.com", age: 28 },
      { name: "John", email: "john@gmail.com", age: 33 },
      { name: "Bob", email: "bob32@gmail.com", age: 33 },
    ],
  };
  let newArray = data.employees.map((emp) => {
    if (emp.age == 33) emp.age = 1;
    return emp;
  });
  console.log(newArray);
```

more about map function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Thank for your answer, but in my nested array, it not work, but i upvoted btw

Comment: check my edited code. if it still not working please post your full code , I will glad to help :)
Thanks for the vote :)

Comment: This does not create a new array.  The `employees` element is an array of objects,`.map()` creates a new array but it still just copies the references from the old array.  This results in your code mutating `data`

Comment: thats true ! I will edit my answer so people will notice that.