# How to update an array using useState Hook

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I've tried to fetch data from a URL and get the result as JSON format, then store not of the object result in my state. but it always returns an empty array.

```
const [genres, setGenres] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getGenres = async () => {
      fetch("https://quote-garden.herokuapp.com/api/v2/genres")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
           for (const g of data.genres) {
             setGenres((oldGenres) => [...oldGenres, g]);
           }          
        });
    };
    getGenres();
  }, []);
```

Here is the code:
I don't see where the problem can be.
ps: I deleted the import so the code is more readable

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
function App() {
  const [quoteOfTheDay, setQuoteOfTheDay] = useState("");
  const [authorOfQod, setAuthorOfQod] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    const getQuoteOfTheDay = async () => {
      fetch("https://quotes.rest/qod?language=en")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          const qod = data.contents.quotes[0].quote;
          const author = data.contents.quotes[0].author;
          setQuoteOfTheDay(qod);
          setAuthorOfQod(author);
        });
    };
    getQuoteOfTheDay();
  }, []);
  const [genres, setGenres] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getGenres = async () => {
      fetch("https://quote-garden.herokuapp.com/api/v2/genres")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          for (const g of data.genres) {
             setGenres((oldGenres) => [...oldGenres, g]);
           } 
        });
      console.log(genres); // genres always empty
    };
    getGenres();
  }, []);
```

```
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Head quoteOfTheDay={quoteOfTheDay} author={authorOfQod} />
      <div className="app__category">
        <QuoteCategory genre="sport" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the preferred way to mutate a React state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966438/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-mutate-a-react-state)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work if you change

```js
for (const g of data.genres) {
    setGenres((oldGenres) => [...oldGenres, g]);
}
```

to

```js
setGenres((oldGenres) => [...oldGenres, ...data.genres]);
```

Comment: Could you post the rest of the file then? There may be another issue at play

Comment: I just Edited the code. Thank you so much for the time.

Comment: I just looked at your code, and genres will be empty on that log because the setGenres function will not have completed yet. If you move that log to outside your useEffect, you will see that genres is populated on the next render

Comment: it works!!! thank you so much for your time. This is something I will pay attention to next time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const getGenres = async () => {
    fetch("https://quote-garden.herokuapp.com/api/v2/genres")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
         setGenres(data.genres);
      });
  };
  getGenres();
}, []);
```

is not enough? :)

Up. If you began you can use `async-await` syntax till the end. It looks more neatly.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const getGenres = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://quote-garden.herokuapp.com/api/v2/genres");
    const { genres } = await response.json();

    setGenres(genres);
  };
  
  getGenres();
}, []);
```

Comment: You also can mutate data before storing by `setGenres(data.genres.map(/* ... */));`

Comment: Tried both of them but nothing

Comment: If you put `debuger` before `setGenres(data.genres);` what will you get in `data.genres`?

Comment: an array of strings where each element of the array is the name of a category of quote

Comment: Wait! Do you want to get genres right after fetch on line `console.log(genres); // genres always empty`?
Of course, you will get `[]` in this place. =)

Answer (score 0):

you should put `genresState` as your dependency

```
const [genresState, setGenres] = useState([])



useEffect(() => {
  const getGenres = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://quote-garden.herokuapp.com/api/v2/genres");
    const { genres } = await response.json();

    setGenres(genres);
  };
  
  getGenres();
}, [genresState]);
```